# Code popup crashes the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, code-block

After the most recent update of the Android app, when I click on some code blocks, the app crashes.

I still don't know for sure why this happens. Stack Overflow code blocks work perfectly while others crash the app.

Comment: Repro'd once on Nexus 5, Lollipop 5.1, either latest version of SE app or 1 version before (forgot the timing).

Comment: Which android version are you using?

Comment: @Abhishek android version 4.4.2

Comment: This is my fault.  The fix for [this bug](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/no-latex-syntax-highlighting-on-mobile-devices/6042#6042) requires a check for the current site, and for some reason there's an intentional exception when asking for a site when transitioning.  Working on a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  I screwed things up big time.

The Android app has a global context that exposes things like the current activity, its site, toolbar, etc.  When I added support for site-specific default code highlighting I took advantage of this:

```
    private String getPrettifyHintFromTags(String[] tags) {
        if (tags == null)
            return null;

        for (String tag : tags) {
            if (PrettifyHinter.containsTag(tag))
                    return PrettifyHinter.get(tag);
        }

        if (PrettifyHinter.containsSite(Current.getCurrentSite()))
            return PrettifyHinter.get(Current.getCurrentSite());

        return null;
    }
```

What I didn't realize was that A) `getCurrentSite` will throw an exception if there is no current activity:

```
Activity act = getCurrentActivity();
if (act == null)
    throw new RuntimeException("getCurrentSite() can only be called when an activity is in the resumed state");
```

B) there is no activity between when the current activity gets `onPause` and the new activity gets `onResume`, C) things that happen between those two points include the new activity's `onCreate` and `onStart` calls.

With all these factors put together, the following sequence of events occurred:

1. You tapped the code block.
2. The question activity started an activity with the code popup intent.
3. The question activity was suspended, setting currentActivity to null.
4. The code popup activity was created, asked to prettify, found no SO tags, asked for the current site, and got an exception, crashing the app.

To mitigate this, I've changed the signature of the method to `String getPrettifyHintFromTags(String[], Site)` and making sure the site is passed in from an appropriate point rather than reaching into the context.